内 (uchi) 肉 (niku) - is there a third word with 3 人 in its kanji?
内 is uchi (inside) and 肉 is niku (meat) - is there a third word with 3 人 in its kanji character?
I am asking because a website mentions that the word 肉 contains the radical 人, ref: https://jisho.org/search/%E8%82%89%20%23kanji

Yes, it means "6-pack".

I'm a bit confused by your question: neither 内 nor 肉 include any 人 element, despite the rough graphical similarity.  As we see in the "Glyph origin" section for 內 (the older form of 内), this is from 冂 ("city outskirts") + 入 ("to enter"), while for 肉, this was originally just a picture of a cut of meat. No 人 in either character.

I tried drawing the kanji at https://kanji.sljfaq.org/ but it didn't find such a kanji. @istrasci is there a way to write that out on the internet or is that only for pen and paper?

@ubershmekel istrasci is pulling your leg.

While the answer to this question is simply "no", this reminded me of a classic joke/riddle that goes like this: "If 木 means tree, 林 means woods, and 森 means forest, what's the meaning of a kanji with four 木? (Answer: jungle)"

@naruto Unfortunately, etymology of Kanjis are not very accessible for non-native speakers.  There just aren't many good online sources that are not written using Kanjis themselves.  For instance, https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/內#Glyph_origin is incomplete.  While https://jisho.org/search/肉%20%23kanji is completely wrong.

Understandably, etymology is an active area of research, so perhaps we should build a more authoritative database, or just not include any etymology at all.

Short Answer
No, as pointed out by Eiríkr Útlendi, both 内 and 肉 does NOT contain 人.
Long Answer
内 : Oracle Bone script consist of 冂 (debated: wilderness/high hall) and 入 (~in, ~enter), Bronze script and further consist of 宀(~house, ~home) and 入.
肉 : just 肉.  The form in Oracle Bone script looks more like 月 (moon), in which they are kept in words like 胃 (stomach) 腸 (intestine).  Perhaps in order to prevent confusion, by 隸書 texts it is changed to the form seen today.
References:
CUHK Etymology Database (in chinese):
https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=肉
https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=内

Fun Facts
1. meaning of 內 vs 入
In《説文》, 內 is explained as "It means 入", while 入 is "It means 內".
2. Meaning of 冂
Although 冂 is said to mean wilderness/city outskirts in 《説文》, which is cited by Wiktionary, this is NOT an established fact.  It is unclear whether 冂 in 《説文》 is the same word as in 內, which should be closer to 宀 for the majority of time.  The character 冂 is so rarely used it is mostly unclear what it meant when it is used alone (mostly in incomplete texts).
冂 is used as a component in 尚/堂/常/高, also, and the original character of 堂, meaning hall.  冂 is also used as a simplified form of (冋/坰), meaning wilderness.  Note that it is not a unseen phenomenon that the same shape being two different Kanji characters.  So some scholars, including 落合淳思 from 立命館大学 in Japan believe that 冂 as seen in Oracle bone script is a 亡失字 lost word, distinct to the 2 use case above.
Reference
some research on 冂, in Japanese:
https://www.hiemalis.org/~acy/mnc/2678201gcd.html
CUHK Etymology Database, in Chinese:
https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=冂

In general, for online source of Kanji etymology I would recommend the etymology database by the Chinese University of Hong Kong: https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/ .  Most other online sources such as Wiktionary just directly quote from 《説文》, which is written in 100CE, more than 1000 years ago.  Understandably, there are some minor mistakes, and the words can shift, or duplicate through time.  The CUHK database cite more variety of sources and interpretation, which is better IMO.

Looking at https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/王#Chinese , the "traditional" interpretation is 《説文》, while "modern" are other scholars / texts.

In most cases, it is unclear what the source of etymology is from on Wiktionary.  The CUHK database will typically state the author, unfortunately not in bibliography standard, yet still better than the others.

The reason I said 人 is in it is because that's the radical that's mentioned here: https://jisho.org/search/%E8%82%89%20%23kanji but my real question wasn't about what the name of the radical is. It's about if there is a kanji with 3 of those. And I think the answer to that is also "no there is no such kanji".

@ubershmekel I see why you have this question now, unfortunately, the website is wrong.

I wouldn't call it "wrong" in the sense that the reason it's listed like that there is so you can find it by searching for that component. It looks like 人 and so when people search by 人 they can find it. It's not trying to give a historical summary of the kanji.

@Leebo I see what you are going for, but by giving such non-orthodox partition of Kanji components, it will lead to incorrect understanding and confusion like this.

I actually looked more into the site and many of the breakdowns are very weird, to name a few https://jisho.org/search/敬%20%23kanji https://jisho.org/search/郷%20%23kanji

these too: https://jisho.org/search/麦%20%23kanji https://jisho.org/search/掛%20%23kanji

It's not the site's data. It comes from resources like KANJIDIC2. Yes, there are weird things about it, but for a free resource like Jisho to provide a "search by parts" function, there aren't really other options. I'm sure if you dig into it, there are explanations for some of the strange breakdowns.I think in some cases they just use what looks close or they go overboard with parts to make sure you get a hit even if you aren't exactly right. Again, it's for convenience of lookups based on appearance, not faithfulness to etymology.

The creator of Jisho, who is a solo dev who makes the site in his free time, might be willing to listen to suggestions about adding an option to hide the parts or adding an expandable explanation near the parts that says what they're for, but he's not always working on the site and thus it might not get done soon. There are email addresses for the site or the site forum if you think it's important and want to give feedback.

@Leebo Interesting, now knowing that they are not professionals, I really do appreciate their work.  I can see how the feature can be useful for learners, despite the "incorrectness" in my perspective.  Now, judging on the correctness of the feature itself, I believe it is still wrong in the UI level, in which it incorrectly took the radical part encoding by face-value, which contradicts with the statement by EDRDG group: "...Where the element alone is not in JIS X 0208, a kanji which contains the element is used instead."

@Leebo I plan to submit a ticket on Github, since I never used Jisho.org, do you know where is best to make them aware of this issue?  As in where is the community most active?  I don't use Mastodon, and I don't want to expose my email address.

@Leebo feel free to chime in on the Github ticket: https://github.com/reline/Jisho/issues/79
